# Slippage Error in node.js script

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

Hi i am creating arbitrage bot which execute 2 swaps and i got error that may indicate that this is occurring because of expectedAmountOut so this might be related to slippage
Code:

```
const slippageTolerance = 0.001; 
const EX1S = sushiPrice * amount * (1 - slippageTolerance) - amount * 0.003;
    const EX2S =
      EX1S / (uniswapPrice * (1 + slippageTolerance)) -
      (EX1S / (uniswapPrice * (1 + slippageTolerance))) * 0.003;
let formattedEX1S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX1S.toString(), "ether");
      let formattedEX2S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX2S.toString(), "ether");
      let dataF = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ["uint256", "uint256"],
        [formattedEX1S, formattedEX2S]
      );

      const gasEstimateF = await contract.estimateGas.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF
      );
      console.log("estimated gas:" + gasEstimateF);

      const gasEstimateWithBuffer = gasEstimateF.mul(120).div(100);
      console.log("estimated gas with buffer:" + gasEstimateWithBuffer);

      const tx = await contract.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF,
        {
          gasLimit: gasEstimateWithBuffer,
          gasPrice: newGasPriceWei,
        }
      );
```